# Visualforce page not returning values

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I have created a visualforce page and custom controller. I am trying to create a list of opportunities on Account where the opportunities are related to the contacts linked to that account however the opportunities are related to a different account.

Contact A linked with Opportunity B and Account C
Contact linked with Account D
List of opportunities on Account C shows opportunity B

```
public with sharing class ApprenticeshipOpportunities_CX {
public List<Opportunity> opps {get; set;}
public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}
public Contact con;
public Account acct;

public ApprenticeshipOpportunities_CX(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.acct = (Account)controller.getRecord();
}
public List<Opportunity> getOpps(){
    contacts = [select id, account.id, opportunity__r.id from Contact where account.id =: acct.id];

    opps = [select id, Name, Account.Name, apprentice_name__c, CloseDate, Amount, Type from Opportunity where recordtype.name = 'Apprenticeships'];
    List<Opportunity> oppstodisplay = new list<Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity o : opps){
        for(Contact c : contacts)
        if(o.apprentice_name__c == c.Opportunity__c){
            oppstodisplay.add(o);
        }

    }
    return oppstodisplay;
}
}

<apex:page standardController="Account" 
extensions="ApprenticeshipOpportunities_CX">
<style>
.fewerMore { display: none;}
</style>
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageMessages />
 <apex:detail relatedList="true"></apex:detail>
<apex:pageblock id="CustomList" title="Third Party Apprenticeship 
Opportunities"  >
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opps}" var="o" rendered="
{!NOT(ISNULL(opps))}">
    <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!o.Account.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!o.Type}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!o.Amount}"></apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!o.CloseDate}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
   <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="
{!NOT(ISNULL(opps))}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel>
 </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conflict between the `getOpps()` method and the getter of your `opps` variable.

Just remove your `opps` variable declaration. You don't need it.

Then, in your `getOpps()` method, declare the opps variable with its type:

```
List<Opportunity> opps = [select id, Name, Account.Name, apprentice_name__c, CloseDate, Amount, Type from Opportunity where recordtype.name = 'Apprenticeships'];
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have removed the opps getter and the visualforce page is still returning a blank pageBlockTable.